# touchevent on div element doesn't work while works on window element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, touch

This may sound a very silly question, but it is driving me nuts. I have a `div` on which I want to append a `touchevent`. This is how I do it:

```
$("#superContainer").bind('touchstart', function(event, passedName) {
    alert("touch start");
    //[more code]
});
```

This approach doesn't work. No alert, nothing. The properties of the `div` `#supercontainer` are `width: 100%; top: 0px`.

The following approach works:

```
$(window).bind('touchstart', function(event, passedName) {
    alert("touch start");
    //[more code]
});
```

But I want to avoid having the whole window binded to an event. I'm using the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: Does your `#superContainer` have a height? And could you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: No it doesn't. I don't think I need that right? I thought it was automatically set. I'll try to build a fiddle right now

Comment: That depends. If the child elements are floated or absolute positioned, the container doesn't automatically get the height

Comment: You need to set the height of the div, normally it doesn't get a height automatically.

Comment: I checked on Chrome with the developer tools and even if I add a height it doesn't work. Moreover mousing over the element the page gets covered, that means it is the width of the screen basically. I'm trying to setup the fiddle but I have problems importing jquery ("$ not defined") -> http://jsfiddle.net/98E35/.

Comment: Hm don't know what's wrong.. Are you using jquery mobile and jquery ui? With those disabled i got this http://jsfiddle.net/BW6kW/3/ I just recently discoverd that the HTML and BODY elements should have a height if you want to use percentages

Comment: Thanks, apparently this work... I have to check what's the difference between your solution and mine...

Comment: Ah now i understand ;) Looks like jquery mobile doesn't like it if you use percentages for height/width. http://jsfiddle.net/BW6kW/5/ Could you test this on your mobile?

Comment: Your code, when ran, gives the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'match' `, by jquery mobile

Comment: Hm i get that too is see now.. When i load i get that message, and then when i click run it works..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47731/discussion-between-masiar-and-robinvda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/, you should use either

```
$(function() {
  // Document is ready
});
```

or

```
jQuery(function( $ ) {
  // Document is ready
});
```

Which was the problem in this case

Also use `.on` instead of `.bind`:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.
>   https://api.jquery.com/bind/